# x509 + asn1: are subjectAltName elements explicit or implicit?

Tags: x509

From https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280:

```
SubjectAltName ::= GeneralNames

GeneralNames ::= SEQUENCE SIZE (1..MAX) OF GeneralName

GeneralName ::= CHOICE {
     otherName                 [0]  AnotherName,
     rfc822Name                [1]  IA5String,
     dNSName                   [2]  IA5String,
     x400Address               [3]  ORAddress,
     directoryName             [4]  Name,
     ediPartyName              [5]  EDIPartyName,
     uniformResourceIdentifier [6]  IA5String,
     iPAddress                 [7]  OCTET STRING,
     registeredID              [8]  OBJECT IDENTIFIER }
```

In the wild I've encountered x509 certificates where this extension is used.

`rfc822Name` and `dNSName` entries are tagged with `0x81` and `0x82` (context-specific bit set plus type)

but `directoryName` is tagged with `0xA4` (context-specific bit set plus constructed bit plus type = EXPLICIT) where Name is defined as...

```
Name ::= CHOICE { -- only one possibility for now --
      rdnSequence  RDNSequence }

RDNSequence ::= SEQUENCE OF RelativeDistinguishedName

DistinguishedName ::=   RDNSequence

RelativeDistinguishedName ::= SET SIZE (1..MAX) OF AttributeTypeAndValue
```

So my question is -- if I'm implementing this ASN1 structure, how do I know which of these elements is EXPLICIT and which are IMPLICIT ?

My understanding is that EXPLICIT is the default and the spec in the RFC doesn't specify anything.

Comment: See appendix A. GeneralNames is defined in the module in A.2 with IMPLICIT TAGS while Name is defined in the module in A.1 with EXPLICIT TAGS.

Comment: Ahhhhh always an appendix thank you. Post as answer if you want the points!

Comment: It's pretty hard to understand the meaning of that appendix!